# Haskell - Transform letters into numbers

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and would like to make a program to turn characters in a string into numbers. Something like this:

```
A = 06
B = 07
C = 08
... Z
```

So for example:

```
Input: Hi 
Output: 14 15
```

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your counting might be one off

```
> import Data.Char(ord,toUpper)
> map (\x -> ord (toUpper x) - ord 'A' + 6) "Hi"
[13,14]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `ord` from `Data.Char`. This interpreter code does what you need:

```
ghci> import Data.Char
ghci> map ord "Hi"
[72, 105]
```

You can create a function from this:

```
import Data.Char

toAscii :: [Char] -> [Int]
toAscii str = map ord str
```

If you want to map letters to numbers so that e.g. `A=1` and `z=58`, you can do this:

```
import Data.Char

toOrder :: [Char] -> [Int]
toOrder str = map (\x -> x - 64) $ map ord str
-- or using composition of `toAscii`
toOrder str = map (\x -> x - 64) $ toAscii str
```